# Can't pass a variable from controller to view - Laravel

Tags: laravel, variables, controller, laravel-blade

I'm trying to pass a variable from controller to view but I got an 'Undefined variable' error.

web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;

Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index']);    
Route::get('/dashboard/{uuid}/download', [DashboardController::class, 'download'])->name('dashboard.download');
```

DashboardController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Licence;
use App\Models\Download;
use Auth;
    
public function index($uuid)
{
    if (Licence::where('user_id', Auth::id())->exists()) {
        $download = Download::where('uuid', $uuid)->firstOrFail();
        return view('dashboard.index', compact('download'));
    } else {
        return redirect('/checkout');
    }
}
        
public function download($uuid)
{
    $download = Download::where('uuid', $uuid)->firstOrFail();
    $pathToFile = storage_path('app/public/plugin.zip');
    return response()->download($pathToFile);
}
```

dashboard/index.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('dashboard.download', $download->uuid) }}">
```

Any idea?

Comment: You are not loading a view...

Comment: Maybe show your `index()` method that calls that view

Comment: `return view('dashboard.index');` doesn't pass any data to the view. Make sure it does

Comment: `return view('dashboard.index', [ 'yourData' => 'foo' ]);`

Comment: @brombeer I just updated my code, but now I have an 'Too few arguments' error...

Comment: `Route::get('/dashboard/{uuid}', [DashboardController::class, 'index']);`  
In route you have to pass 1 params `uuid` to have uuid in controller function `public function index($uuid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The index function in the `DashboardController` cannot find `$uuid`. You already declared and passed parameter `$uuid` to the `index` function in the `DashboardController`, but `$uuid` have not been defined. Change

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index']);
```

To

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{uuid}',[DashboardController::class, 'index']);
```

**Notice:** You have to pass `uuid` as a parameter to the `'/dashboard'` route  so that the variable `$uuid` will be given a value(defined) through the url when a route is visited.  Ensure that the all url of the index page in your project is also modified to accommodate the new parameter(`uuid`), else you will get a 404 error.
When you visit

```
/dashboard/1
```

`$uuid` gets a value of `1`, and so on.